# Change the html width automatically on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Halo, Stackoverflows! 
I'm currently building a responsive grid website that will show some
pictures of a photographer. But, I guess it's even complicated to build this
kind of site than I thought...

Currently, the problem is that I cannot find a way to build a javascript that targets the html width and that will trigger the html width to automatically change every time a user changes the browser size.

I used this code, but it requires a user to refresh the page every time he/she resizes his/her browser.

```
<script>
$( 'html' ).width(p.innerWidth() + 25)
</script>
```

Is there any javascript that will be triggered on the browser resize and change the html width automatically without refreshing the site?

Thank you!

Comment: Use $( window ).resize(function(){}); for JQuery

Comment: @PatrickGeyer Thank you for your fast response! Well.. Unfortunately It does not support Firefox...

Comment: $( window ).resize(function(){
$( 'html' ).width(p.innerWidth() + 25)} Anyway Is this the full code?

Comment: What he said, but also, I would try to use CSS to do it all especially if you are shooting for mobile. Ive found forcing phones to handle all the JS can suck. Using either flex width and percentages with CSS or media queries with break points both work well.

Comment: I don't think you need JavaScript for this (although `resize` would accomplish what you want), see http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/gawcP/

Comment: From the looks of it, CSS would be a far cleaner way to do this, is there any reason you're not using CSS width and height %'s?

Comment: Well.. I know the media queries are the best solution for this problem, but since the site is full-screen with four-columns(25% for each), I expected a javascript that will trigger the html width to change on browser resize.

Comment: If you want to affect html tag, don't use quotes.